# setting up Dns and subdomains

Tags: subdomain

I have bought a domain and I want to use multiple subdomains for different sections of my application. I want the server to have it own subdomain i.e. `server.example.com`, I want the landing page to have the URL of the domain i.e. `www.example.com` and I want to have the web application have the subdomain `app.example.com`.

To point the server subdomain to the host(digitalocean) I need to add their nameserver to the domain. To point my client subdomain to the host(vercel) I also need to add their nameserver. I have done this.
Is it a idea good to point multiple nameservers to one domain as i have done?

Also my server subdomain shows an `ssl protocol error` error after sometime then it goes back online. What might be the issue?
Is my configuration as stated above correct? if not which approach do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i bought a domain from dynadot and wanted to have several subdomains,one for the frontend and another for the backend. For frontend i hosted in vercel and for the server i was using digital ocean, and i had to setup digital oceans name servers in my domain host -dynadot so as to point my server subdomain to them. in doing that i could not set up a dns record or another nameserver in my domain host since i already have set up digital oceans nameserver already.What i was to do is to go digital ocean and add my vercel dns records from there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean nameserver?

A ***name***server is a D***N***S server. It translates DNS addresses (like app.example.com) to ip addresses (like 1.2.3.4). When you set the nameserver for a domain you are saying "If you need to look up IP addresses for this domain or any subdomains you should talk to ___". If you list more than one nameserver, one will be tried basically at random.

Typically you would have a pair of identical nameservers (often provided by your DNS registrar) configured for a domain, and those nameservers would have DNS records for each of the subdomains you wanted to configure. If you were operating google-service.example.com and heroku-service.example.com you would not use the nameservers from Google or Heroku. You would just have records that point to them.

If you do need to use different nameservers, make sure you are configuring them for the specific sub-domains rather than the domain itself. All nameservers at a particular level should have identical records. If they do not, records which exist on only 1 of the 2 nameservers will return "wrong" results when the client randomly selects a nameserver and happens to pick the "wrong" one.